# Can IPv6 be disabled on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ipv6, netflix

**TL;DR: Can I disable IPv6 on an iPad?**

Strange issue that I've just figured out. For months I've been seeing content show up in Netflix that should be unavailable to me (I'm in Canada), or things that should be available not showing up. Sometimes I'll pause a show and when I restart it, I'll get an error that it's not available in my region!

I just realized that I'm getting my IPv6 connectivity through a Hurricane Electric tunnel, which of course is American. I'm thinking this explains a lot of the transient problems I've been having with Netflix, especially w/r/t regions. My primary device for viewing is an iPad, so I want to disable IPv6 on it.

It doesn't seem like it's possible; I can't even see what my IP is from the network settings, but thought I'd throw it out there and see if anyone know any tricks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - iOS has no profile or setting to disable IPv6. Even if you jailbreak, I don't know how to set that on iOS operating systems.

Yes I am also using a Hurricane Electric tunnel for IPv6. I have similar problems with my two iMac computers. I have to set my IPv6 to "link local only". This fixed my connection problems.

This partial solution (controlling the router) only works over WiFi though - cellular data carrier routing also would need to be changed if you can't allow IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 can be disabled completely on macOS by running this command in Terminal: 10.7.x – 10.11.x<br> $ networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi 10.10.3 or above<br> $ networksetup -setv6off "Wi-Fi"

Comment: iPad. Not macOS

Comment: Yeah I was just responding to his comment about setting his iMacs to link-local.

Comment: According to this it looks like we might be out of luck,b but I’m gonna look for a way to possibly tunnel the IPv6 connection instead. <br> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

Comment: @Eric: I am not sure I understand your last comment. Are you trying to create an 6in4 tunnel between Hurricane Electric and your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you can’t disable IPv6 in iOS but if you have access to the router settings, you can disable it there so that the router no longer connects using IPv6. Worked for me in keeping my home automation and media system accessible.

Comment: True, but if I'm going to the trouble of setting up with an IPv6 tunnel provider, I probably want IPv6 in general!